# Authentication issue with api request

Tags: rest-api

I have wrote a api for a mobile application. When i try to test this api on my browser by providing the url i am getting an error

```
<Errors>
  <Error>
      <errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
      <message>Session expired or invalid</message>
  </Error>
</Errors>
```

My controller

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/mycall/*')
global with sharing class RESTCaseController {
  @HttpGet
  global static String getOpenCases() {
    return 'Success';
  }
}
```

The url i am trying to access from browser

> https://pm-devorg-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/mycall

Can anyone guide me what i am missing out here.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a few things in play here

1) Check the scope of your connected app. You should have the appropriate access based on the operation you are doing. For testing purposes, you may want to set this to 'Full Access' once to see if this is an issue.

[image]

2) Check that your request includes a valid auth token by setting it in a manner similar to

```
client.getClientInfo().instanceUrl+bodyURL+" -H "+'"'+"Authorization: Bearer "+client.getAuthToken()+'"';
```

3) You did not really mention if you are using the [Salesforce Android SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android), it handles the session management automatically so you should not run into such issues if you use that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first authenticate to Salesforce and get the access token. You should then add that access token to your API request. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)
You will have to replace 'token' with your access token.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you'll need a Authorization header with a value of Bearer + a session Id or an access token gained via oAuth or some other authentication mechanism. If you just want to test the REST call from something like Postman, you can use the session id from a current session as the Bearer Token.

This [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) is also a great start for understanding oAuth.